# Matplotlib : How to get a triangular matrix of subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I would like to have a set of subplots divided in three lines with one subplot on the first line, two on the second and three on the third. I did the following :

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True, ncols=3, nrows=3)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(0, i+1):
        axes[i, j].plot(x, np.sin((i+j) *x))
```

Thus I get : 
[image]

How can I remove the three empty plots ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this?

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True, ncols=3, nrows=3)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if i<j:
            axes[i, j].axis('off')
        else:
            axes[i, j].plot(x, np.sin((i+j) *x))
```

It seems to produce a plot you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to get back xticks of top axes ?

Comment: @Ger well, if you disable `sharex=True` you'll get all the xticks labeled. Otherwise you can use `set_ticklabels` method of individual axes instances.